# Cannot run XMonad on Voidlinux properly

Tags: xmonad

It runs but I get this error everytime

```
$ cabal install xmonad xmonad-contrib
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
Symlinking 'xmonad'

$ cat ~/.xinitrc
exec ~/.cabal/bin/xmonad

$ cat ~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs 
import XMonad

main = do
  xmonad $ defaultConfig

$ ~/.cabal/bin/xmonad 
XMonad is recompiling and replacing itself another XMonad process because the current process is called "xmonad" but the compiled configuration should be called "xmonad-x86_64-linux"
XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/d/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
XMonad doing recompile because some files have changed.
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/d/.xmonad/xmonad.hs
Loaded package environment from /home/d/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.3/environments/default

xmonad.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘XMonad’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘xmonad-0.15’.
    You can run ‘:set -package xmonad’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import XMonad
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Please check the file for errors.

/home/d/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux: executeFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Serial number of failed request:  7
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and stumbled across a solution that worked.  Hope it helps.

"We can manually specify a package db for ghc-pkg so it’ll find our cabal modules:

$ ghc-pkg --package-db ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db list
...
xmonad-0.15
xmonad-contrib-0.16
...

And to make it permanent we can symlink the package.db file as a ghc config:

$ mkdir -p ~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.3/
$ ln -s ~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db ~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.8.3/package.conf.d

The name of the folder x86_64-linux-8.8.3 may differ, this one worked for me.

And now ghc-pkg list should find xmonad and compiling with ghc should find our missing cabal modules."

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.